# How could I send post parameters with redirect() not using session in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, post, parameters, request

How can I send parameters to a post method with redirect() *without using a session* in CodeIgniter (`$this->session->set_flashdata` or `set_userdata`)? In Java I used to use `request.setAttribute('key', 'value');
If I use session it will affect another browser tab... and if I use URL (get) method, it will expose the parameters...

Comment: If I use session it will affect another browser tab... and if I use URL (get) method, it will expose the parameters...

Comment: try using `$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');` and `$this->session->mark_as_flash(array('item', 'item2'));`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following pattern:

redirect('controller_name/method_name/' . $parameter_value);

Comment: It must to be in post method

Comment: If I use session it will affect any other browser tab... and if I use URL method, it will expose the parameters...